# Euler-Lagrange equations in 2D with line-wise constraint

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation

I need to tackle a variational optimization problem in two variables with an integral-constraint with respect to one variable and a point-wise constraint with respect to the other variable. One may want to call it a 'line-wise' constraint. Specifically, seeking for $f\colon [a, b]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align} \tag{1}
\text{minimize} & \quad \int_a^b \int_a^b \; K(x, y, f, f_x, f_y) \; dx \; dy \\
\text{subject to} & \quad \int_a^b \; G(x, y, f) \; dx \; = \; 0 \quad \forall \; y \in (a, b) \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $f_x$, $f_y$ are the derivatives of $f$ by $x$ and $y$ respectively and assuming natural boundary conditions, i.e. resulting in Neumann boundary conditions for the final PDE.

I would expect that one can formulate this by using a Lagrange multiplier that is a function in $y$, yielding a Lagrangian like so

\begin{equation} \tag{3}
L \;=\; K + \lambda(y) G
\end{equation}

then apply Euler-Lagrange equations for two independent variables on $L$ as found in Arfken, 'Mathematical Methods for Physicists' or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_several_variables_with_single_derivative).

There is plenty of literature that treats the case of one or several integral constraints in one or several variables or of a point-wise constraint in one variable. I did not find the case of 'line-wise' constraints explicitly treated in literature and my knowledge of calculus of variations is too fragile to confidently derive this case. So I would kindly ask for

- confirmation of my intuition that (3) is the proper way to tackle problem (1, 2) or a correction otherwise
- pointers to literature where this case is handled
- hints how to derive (3) by variation or by reducing it to known cases

Edit: I read that Lagrange multipliers can only handle holonomic constraints, i.e. $G$ must not depend on $f_y$. It appears to be fine if functionals in integral constraints depend on derivatives with respect to the variable of integration.

Additional question:
Do I understand correctly that $G$ in (2) may well depend on $f_x$ but not on $f_y$ to count as holonomic, as it is integrated over $x$? I.e. (2) could also be written with $G(x, y, f, f_x)$.

Sorry if I overlooked a duplicate of this question. I searched for them and there does not seem to be one.